# send command to card reader get response c#

Tags: c#

I have a card reader which is used to register employee entrance. It works in offline and online mode

offline means it stores all data(say for one month) and after connecting to computer via telnet admin sends a "read" command and the reader sends back all data stored in one month.

In online mode again the reader is connected to computer via telnet and whenever someone shows the card to reader, reader sends the data and application shows the result instantly.

how can I figure this out? I have used asynchronous socket also but no good results.

Any help is appreciated.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string ip = Convert.ToString(IP_textBox.Text);
        TcpClient telnet = new TcpClient();
        telnet.Connect("172.16.0.133", 5010);

        //sending "read" to Device
        //string data = "read";

        //byte[] recieveData = new byte [32768];
        NetworkStream readStream = telnet.GetStream();
        if (readStream.CanWrite)
        {
            byte[] readData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("read");
            readStream.Write(readData, 0, readData.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            telnet.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            return;
        }
        if (readStream.CanRead)
        {
            byte[] recieveData = new byte[telnet.ReceiveBufferSize];


            readStream.Read(recieveData, 0, (int)telnet.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string out_string = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recieveData);
            // System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            //string out_string = enc.GetString(recieveData, 0, recieveData.Length);
            MessageBox.Show("Im here");
        }
        else
        {
            telnet.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your problem, this question is too general. What is your exact problem? Do you have some kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, TELNET is a protocol to which you must stick. It's not enough to just connect a `TcpClient` to the TELNET port and send commands.

You might want to look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd348022-7c71-4b08-9f94-999b18592d3e/developing-a-telnet-application-in-c